# black circles on eyes

Tags: coloration-discoloration, face, blemishes, periorbital-dark-circles

Except of improve the life that influence our health and  creating this black circles down of eyes what we can we do to fix those circles.As an example can i use an ice on the black circles down of eyes to make those black circles go away?what can I use( not chemical ways ).